# Handle special characters in blackberry and store it to database

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

i have web service and i'm feteching data from webservice and storing that data into database,but i that was giving exception  and i have checked that my databae is created succesfully on device and i'm closing properly my database opened successfully
i think it's problem of special character in my web service data, i have some stories in my webservice, and that conatin some special characters...,and when i try to insert them to my database they give SQL LOGIC ERROR
try{
                conn = (StreamConnection) Connector.open("http://tandonindia.com/story_new_xml?user=500"+";deviceside=true"/*+";interface=wifi"*/);

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
            docBuilderFactory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
            docBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(true);

            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();    

            docBuilder.isValidating();      

            is = conn.openInputStream();    
            doc = docBuilder.parse(is);     
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); 
            System.out.println ("ROOT ELEMENT OF DOCUMENT IS=  " +  doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            //add(new LabelField(""+  doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName()));

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++){
                //System.out.println(""+nodeList.getLength());

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                      Element element = (Element) node;
                      NodeList nodelist = element.getElementsByTagName("Week");
                      Element element1 = (Element) nodelist.item(0);
                      NodeList fstNm = element1.getChildNodes();
                      System.out.print("Week-- " + (fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString());

                      Element element2 = (Element) node;
                      NodeList nodelist1 = element2.getElementsByTagName("Year");
                      Element element3 = (Element) nodelist1.item(0);
                      NodeList fstNm1 = element3.getChildNodes();
                      System.out.println("\nYear-- "+(fstNm1.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString());


                      //For retriving text from node notification
                      Element element4 = (Element) node;
                      NodeList nodelist2 = element4.getElementsByTagName("subject");
                      Element element5 = (Element) nodelist2.item(0);
                      NodeList fstNm2 = element5.getChildNodes();
                      System.out.println("subject--"  + (fstNm2.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString());


                      //For retriving text from node Link
                      Element element15 = (Element) node;
                      NodeList nodelist21 = element15.getElementsByTagName("storypath");
                      Element element51 = (Element) nodelist21.item(0);
                      NodeList fstNm22 = element51.getChildNodes();
                      System.out.println("storypath--"  + (fstNm22.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString());

                      try {
                            db2 = DatabaseFactory.open(str);
                             db2.beginTransaction();
                             Statement statmnt2 = db2.createStatement("INSERT into tbstory(Week,Year,subject,storypath) VALUES("+"'"+(fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString()+"','"+(fstNm1.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString()+"','"+(fstNm2.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString()+"','"+(fstNm22.item(0)).getNodeValue().toString()+"')");
                             System.out.println("INSERTING STORYIESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");

                             statmnt2.prepare();
                             statmnt2.execute();
                             statmnt2.close();

                             db2.commitTransaction();
                             db2.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            db2.close();
                            System.out.println("1111222333"+e.toString());

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }

            }
            System.out.println("----------------");

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("error 1"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

and the error i got is below
net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseException: INSERT into tbstory(Week,Year,subject,story[0.0] path) VALUES('25','2013','PRIZE VEGETABLE!','Baba told this story to the students at Kodaikanal.

---

```
  now this time i have very less content , again i got the error on INSERT query and how can i find that which character is giving me error, i'll post my exception while adding a small string in my Database.. can u tell me according to you which character is giving  error  or how can i figure out  which character is giving me error

net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseException: INSERT into tbstory(storypath) VALUES('O[0.0] ne day, the Pandit came excitedly and told Rabidas, a cobbler, "My friend Today the queen is coming [0.0] to have the holy bath. I have been called to do the rit[0.0] uals; for today is a very special day, whoever has a dip in mother Ganga could emerge all pure. Do C[0.0] ome Don't miss this opportunity" Rabidas shook his head and said "Man changa to katooti me Ganga", p[0.0] ointing to his leather bag, (if mind is pure Ganga will[0.0]  be in my leather bag).
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] Angrily the Pandit went away muttering, "When will this fool understand the truth and try to earn Go[0.0] d's Grace?"  His life will be spent in the company of  this disgusting leather only'.
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] In the evening the Pandit came panting, "Rabi, What a miracle occurred today  Ganga Mayya Blessed ou[0.0] r queen with a golden bangle and told her she will get the second one when a person as pure and as d[0.0] evoted as she come to there to dip in the holy river. T[0.0] omorrow the whole city of Kashi will come and see who that lucky Blessed person is".
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] Rabi said "My dear friend It must be you only; for who can be more purer and devoted than you who ta[0.0] ke hundreds of people for holy bath every day?"
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] Pleased and puffed up with pride the Pandit said, "I know it must be me only. Tomorrow I will be the[0.0]  first person to take the holy dip".
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] Next day, the Pundit came late in the evening with an air of dejection over him. Rabi asked "So, my [0.0] friend did you get the second bangle?
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] Rabi closed his eyes and silently prayed "Oh mother, why don't you save this poor Pundit from this d[0.0] ilemma? I know you are everywhere and  manifest anything at any time. Then he put his hand into his [0.0] leather bag and Lo Wonder  of wonders A shinning gold b[0.0] angle emerged
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] The Pandit was spellbound at this great miracle. He bowed down to the cobbler in all humility.
[0.0] 
[0.0]  
[0.0] 
[0.0] "My dear, you have opened my eyes. All work is worship of God; Inner Purity is greater than Outer Pu[0.0] rity.'): SQL logic error or missing database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of BBOS are you testing with? I've found that early releases of OS 5 throw the "Sql logic error" exception when you try to use transactions.  The only work around is to switch to implicit transactions - just skip the call to beginTransaction/commitTransaction.  This affects all BBOS apps versions between 5.0.0.0 and 5.0.0.400 as well as 5.0.0.402, 5.0.0.405, 5.0.0.602.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid formatting problems like this or [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/), you should not embed strings directly into SQL statements but always use parameters:

```java
Statement statmnt2 = db2.createStatement(
    "INSERT INTO tbstory(Week,Year,subject,storypath) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
statmnt2.prepare();
statmnt2.bind(1, fstNm.item(0).getNodeValue().toString());
statmnt2.bind(2, fstNm1.item(0).getNodeValue().toString());
statmnt2.bind(3, fstNm2.item(0).getNodeValue().toString());
statmnt2.bind(4, fstNm22.item(0).getNodeValue().toString());
statmnt2.execute();
statmnt2.close();
```